# Mi band scrolling example

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll

Does anyone know how this type of scrolling is called (so that you scroll full div length at a time) and if there's any templates for such. Mainly to the sides, up and down is simple.

http://www.mi.com/en/miband/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The plugin used in the website is this http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Comment: Thank you for this, exactly what I was looking for!